# Problems with the first element of a matrix after realloc

Tags: c, matrix, realloc

So I'm trying to crop a matrix , then use realloc to free the extra memory left after the croping is done

This is the code , and the output :

[image]

As you can see , there is something wrong with v[0][0].

However , if I delete the code with the realloc , it's all good . I'm probably doing something wrong as I've never used realloc before , especially not on a matrix .

Comment: Please also tag the language you use (I assume C). Also show the source code as text, not as a screenshot, so it is easier for people to work with the code.

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do you call the function?  Your line `**v = realloc(*v, nl*sizeof(int *));` is highly problematic — I think, but since I can't see your calling code or copy the code because its an image, it's hard to double check.  The output should also be copied to the question as text; people shouldn't have to suffer through reading your images.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the reallocations in your crop method.

### Incorrect call

The call

> ```
> **v=realloc(*v,nl*sizeof(int*));
> ```

is incorrect for reallocating for fewer raster lines.  The fact that `*v` is equivalent to `v[0]`, which you reallocate again in the following loop, would be a clue.  The fact that you have different levels of indirection of `v` on the left-hand and right-hand sides would be an even stronger clue.  What you appear to intend is

```
v = realloc(v, nl * sizeof(int *));
```

... or even better ...

```
v = realloc(v, nl * sizeof(*v));
```

### Memory leak

You never free the allocations for the raster lines you crop off, and then you lose those pointers when you shrink the allocation for `v`.  Leaking that memory rather defeats the purpose of reallocating.  You need to free the unwanted raster lines before reallocating `v`.

### Unsafe reallocation

Reallocation does not necessarily happen in-place, even when the allocation is shrunk.  You want to shrink the allocation to which `v` points (as my correction above makes clear), but `v` is passed to your function *by value*, so the revised value received from `realloc()` is not communicated back to the caller.  It may be that the revised value is the same as the original one, in which case you luck out, but if not then you not only leak all the reallocated memory, but you also leave the caller with a dangling pointer.

### No provision for reallocation failure

Since you're shrinking the allocations, it's unlikely that any of your reallocations will fail.  Nevertheless, nothing guarantees that `realloc()` will succeed even in such cases.  If it fails in any given case, then

1. You leak the previously-allocated memory by overwriting the pointer to it with `NULL`.
2. You have no way to report the problem to the caller.

The usual pattern for safe reallocation requires a temporary variable for the return value of `realloc()`:

```
int *t = realloc(v[i], nc * 3 * sizeof(*v[i]));

if (t) {
    v[i] = t;
} else {
    // handle reallocation error ...
}
```

Comment: One more question , if you have time ? How do I free the extra rows and columns of that matrix ?

Comment: @Andrei, you free the space for all columns in each extra row by passing the pointer to each of those rows to the `free()` function (once each).  Having done that, reallocating the space for the list of row pointers, as you're already trying to do, will clean up the space allocated to the unneeded pointers themselves.